# how to render a JS variable into a html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript and want to be able to display a JS variable onto my page without the user going into the console as it is neater, and I find a lot of people don't know about the console, and I don't want to use the `alert()` code. Can anyone help?

Comment: so what you have done so far? what you have tried on your own? a small snippet of your code, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  For example, you might simply set the `innerText` property of an element on your page.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Anyway, this site is not a tutorial site. Pls, search for a nice little tutorial which will teach you JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The code below accesses the paragraph with id "test" and print the value of "testVariable" into it.

```js
var testVariable = "hello";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testVariable;
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need but this example is very simple i recommend you to google more and to keep open the [JavaScript Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for any questions.

The definition for `innerHTML`.

> The Element property innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML markup
> contained within the element.

```js
// Your variable
let name = "Jhon"

// Get the HTML tag by ID and set the innerHTML
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello <span id="name"></span></p>
</div>
```